# Is it possible to make ERC20 tokens that the issuer originally has all controls over them?

Tags: erc-20, erc

I am wondering if the issuer of the ERC20 token can move tokens from user A to user B, without getting the allownace from user A. Is it posssible? If it is, how should I code the ERC20 contract?

Comment: it is definitely possible. can you add some context about why you need it and what have you tried ?

Comment: Technically it is possible, but the ```openzeppelin``` implementation does not allow it https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol. Usually they code it according to the standard which means its _likely_ is not allowed by the standard. We have to check docs that describes standard to make sure. However you can take this ```ERC20``` contract above and modify according to your aim. It would be a valid contract you could use in production, but it might not meet with ```ERC20``` standard any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERC20 token is just a smart contract. If you develop a new ERC20 token contract you can write whatever logic you want in it - as long as you implement all the functionality required by the standard. The standard doesn't state *how* things should be implemented - it only states what functionality has to be implemented.

In your case you should do something like this:

1. Get some ERC20 contract template, for example from OpenZeppelin
2. Store the address of the deployer. Easiest with OpenZeppelin's Ownable library, for example
3. In `transfer` (and probably similarily in `transferFrom`) the default functionality checks that the one who transfers is the token owner. Change/append this functionality to allow also the deployer/owner to transfer tokens from whoever.

Comment: Could you share place in the docs of the ERC20 standard which allows to omit allowance of the token during the transfer? I can not say for sure standard allows it.

Comment: The standard (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) doesn't say much about how the functions should be implemented. If you look at the `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions in the standard, they only say that certain checks SHOULD happen - not that they MUST happen. Even if it said MUST, the token would be just fine in all DEXes with any weird code in it, since it's almost impossible to automatically detect whether a contract is 100% standard compliant.

Comment: Thank you for sharing info regarding standard. What I keep in mind is block explorer decompiler which should allow to check source code for any contract _in public_ networks. Here is an example for the one of the top```ERC721``` contracts on goerly testnet https://goerli.etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0xdf831a908aaaaa336ce6b9f477fecb1cc34d2f77. 
I pay extra attention to this issue because minting a token is an investment and after several years of usage I don't want to see all my tokens has been dismissed from the account by the issuer, but for now it is a standard compliant behaviour.